# libvirt will not start VMs with "error: Invalid value '+cpu' for 'cgroup.subtree_control': Invalid argument"

Tags: kvm, qemu, cgroups, libvirt

On one workstation I have, libvirt has stopped working; it'll no longer start VMs:

```
$ virsh --connect qemu:///system 'start westerley-pool'
error: Failed to start domain westerley-pool
error: Invalid value '+cpu' for 'cgroup.subtree_control': Invalid argument
```

This machine is using the cgroupv2 unified hierarchy (which is [supposed to be supported as of 4.9.0](https://libvirt.org/news.html)). Enabled controllers are memory and pids (checked via `cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cgroup.subtree_control`), so it's not surprising cpu does not work. But the [libvirt cgroups documentation](https://libvirt.org/cgroups.html) says the controller is not mandatory, it just won't be used if not available.

I have tried restarting libvirtd.service, just in case that'd fix it. No change.

The documentation also says I can explicitly set which controllers to use, so I tried setting `cgroup_controllers = [ "memory" ]` in `/etc/libvirt/qemu.conf` (it was previously not set). I again restarted libvirtd.service; still does not work.

I didn't see anything in the logs other than a repeat of the above error message.

I'd rather not enable the cpu controller as I believe it has a performance cost, and I don't need it.

OS: Debian testing
libvirt: 5.0.0-3, from Debian.
kernel: 4.19.0-5-amd64, again Debian.

How can I get libvirt working on this machine again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Updated on June 30)
Make `/etc/systemd/system/libvirtd.service.d/cpu.conf` with its content

```
[Service]
CPUQuota=10000%
```

and everything works fine in my environment. This is an upstream bug
as recognized and fixed by the upstream developers:
https://libvirt.org/git/?p=libvirt.git;a=commit;h=1d49cdcd116186e079db5668893da17f56141652

I submitted a detailed bug report to Debian as
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=931243
with a patch.

Ryutaroh Matsumoto